# Sprite Kit How to change physics body programatically

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

How can I change a sprite's physics body programatically?
Here's what I'm doing:

```
[mySprite removeFromParent];
mySprite.physicsBody = [MySprite body2];
// body setup
[myContainer addChild: mySprite];
```

But somehow it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's my hero character, he's composed of 3 bodies

1. feet - larger circle as a feet sensor
2. polygon - the one I want to flip horizontally
3. smaller circle - it is there pinned to the polygon so that the textures follow the other bodies

[image]

Comment: What do you intend to do? What do you expect to happen here, and what is actually happening? All I get from the code is that you remove a sprite from the scene and add it to some other node, while apparently adding or replacing the physics body.

Comment: I'm trying to change the physics body when my hero changes the direction he's facing, but when I run this code (I'm removing and then adding the sprite because I thought it would be better to change the body not it the scene) the body doesn't change, it's the same

Comment: Or what would be the best approach for changing the body when my hero changes direction (only left/right)?

Comment: Rotate the body by rotating the sprite. Unless you want to change the body's shape that's all you need to do. You didn't post the body2 method so I can't tell if maybe the body is in fact the same.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is a polygon body from a path, rotating would not do it, it must be mirrorred (flipped horizontally)
I added a screenshot of my hero character

Comment: You can use two sprites with two different bodies, only enable one or the other at any one time. Ie set one sprite as hidden, its body's contactTestBitMask to 0.

Comment: Thanks for tip, worked like a charm, the xScale = -1 approach worked as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mirror the sprite like this :

```
mySprite.xScale = -1; // assuming the scale desired is indeed 1.
```

I believe that you can do the same with a SKShapeNode, so you can do the same with your physics body.